# How to track user invites in Android app?

Tags: android

I am implementing a feature "Invite friends to download app from Play Store" in my app. I want to track if the respective friend(s) installed the app. I've a userID maintained for every user in my backend.
Is there a way to accomplish this?
Can I pass a query param with Invitee's User ID to the App's Play store URL and capture it somehow when somebody downloads the app based on the invite?

Answer (score 0):

You could let the invite URL point to your own server. When it gets fetched, you can count and then redirect to the play store.

Of course you wouldn't know if the user finished the installation.

Comment: I want to be able to track if the installations were made using the invite. The solution you pointed out doesn't accomplish that.